# How to see the content of a Gensim-generated dictionary?

Tags: python, data-structures, nltk, gensim, topic-modeling

I am running topic modeling using Gensim. Before creating the document-term matrix, one needs to create a dictionary of tokens.

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokenized_reviews)
doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(rev) for rev in tokenized_reviews]
```

But, I don't understand what kind of object "dictionary" is.

So, when I type:

```
type(dictionary)
```

I get

> gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary

Is this a dictionary ( a kind of data structure)? If so, why can't I see the content (I am just curious)?

When I type

```
dictionary
```

I get:

> <gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary at 0x1bac985ebe0>

The same issue exists with some of the objects in NLTK.

If this is a dictionary (as a data structure), why I am not able to see the keys and values like any other Python dictionary?

Thanks,
Navid

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific `Dictionary` class implemented by the Gensim project.

It will be very similar in interface to the standard Python `dict` (and other various Dictionary/HashMap/etc types you may have used elsewhere).

However, to see exactly what it can do, you should consult the class-specific documentation:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html

Like a `dict`, you can do typical operations:

```py
len(dictionary)  # gets number of entries
dictionary[key]  # gets the value at a certain key (word)
dictionary.keys()  # gets all stored keys
```

The reason you see a generic `<gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary at 0x1bac985ebe0>` when you try to display the value of the `dictionary` itself is that it hasn't defined any convenience display-string with more info - so you're seeing the default for any random Python object. (Such dictionaries are usually far too large to usefull dump their full contents whenever asked, generically, to "show yourself".